# Finding out who else is referring, big data

Tags: python, memory, data-mining, bigdata

I have 50 million rows of data like:

```
referring_id,referred_id
1000,1001
1000,1002
1001,1000
1001,1002
1002,1003
```

The goal is to find all the cases that share incoming connections, numerical examples should help:

If we want to calculate the measure for **1001**, we can see that it has incoming from 1000, so we look who else has incoming connection from 1000, and that is 1002.
So the result would be **[1002]**.

For **1002** we can see 1000 and 1001 are referring to 1002, so that means we look who else do they refer to; result being **[1001,1000]** (1000 refers 1001, 1001 refers 1000).

If it would be smaller data, I would just store for every `referring` a set of outgoing connections, and then loop over `referred` and take a union over all those that have incoming connections.

The problem is that this doesn't fit in memory.

I'm using `csv` to loop over the file and process the lines one at a time not to load it into memory, even though I have 16gb ram.

Does anyone have an idea how to handle it?

Comment: Have you had a look at http://hadoop.apache.org/ ? Another way would possibly be, splitting the data into datasets that fit into memory and joining them later.

Comment: I think it has to be the latter solution indeed. I know of hadoop, but that's so much overhead when I'm hoping there's a solution of more of an algorithmic nature.

Comment: But I think that it can actually fit in memory, just I have to skip doing other things in that script, and loop over the file twice (once to create the structure, and then once to get a result for a row and immediate write it to file)

Comment: It actually takes 12gb, so it is quite a close call.

Comment: You may also have luck if you sort your dataset by the second column, so that when you want to find all the entries with, say, `1002` in the second column, you know they're all next to each other and you don't have to keep that data in memory any more once you stop seeing it. `sort -n -k 2 -t,` is pretty memory efficient if you're using Linux (Sort numerically, by second column, using , as a separator)

Answer (score 1):

You should give [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) a try. It uses NumPy arrays to store the data. This can help to save memory. For example, an integer has the size of 8 bytes instead of 24 in Python 2 or 28 in Python 3. If the numbers are small, you might be able to use `np.int16` or `np.int32` to reduce the size to 2 or 4 bytes per integer.

This solution seems to fit your description:

```
s = """referring_id,referred_id
1000,1001
1000,1002
1001,1000
1001,1002
1002,1003"""

import csv

import numpy as np

pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s), dtype=np.int16) 
#  use: df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', dtype=np.int16) 
by_refered = df.groupby('referred_id')['referring_id'].apply(frozenset)
by_refering = df.groupby('referring_id')['referred_id'].apply(frozenset)

with open('connections.csv', 'w') as fobj:
    writer = csv.writer(fobj)
    writer.writerow(['id', 'connections'])
    for x in by_refered.index:
        tmp = set()
        for id_ in by_refered[x]:
            tmp.update(by_refering[id_])
        tmp.remove(x)
        writer.writerow([x] + list(tmp))
```

Content of `connections.csv`:

```
id,connections
1000,1002
1001,1002
1002,1000,1001
1003
```

Depending on your data you might get away with this. If there are many repeated connections, the number of sets and their size may be small enough. Otherwise, you would need to use some chunked approach.

Comment: Never knew that the data types are smaller in pandas than stdlib types! However, the groupby really makes the RAM explode, so it's not usable like that.